# Dynamically access json object w/o keys

Tags: jquery

I am writing some code to generate data grid form json data.I know there are multiple free libraries available for doing the same.
Below is my piece of code

```
  var columnDefs=[
    {title:"Sr.No",fieldName:"srno",dataType:"int",isHidden:true},
    {title:"Model No.",fieldName:"modelId",dataType:"int"},
    {title:"Name",fieldName:"name",dataType:"string"},
    {title:"Brand",fieldName:"brandName",dataType:"string"},
    {title:"Price",fieldName:"Price",dataType:"double"},
];
var rowData=[
    {srno:"P1",modelId:"1",name:"Moto G3",brandName:"Motorola",price:"13000"},
    {srno:"P2",modelId:"2",name:"Asus ZenFone 2",brandName:"Asus",price:"13000"},
    {srno:"P3",modelId:"3",name:"Lenovo K3 Note",brandName:"Lenovo",price:"9900"},
    {srno:"P4",modelId:"4",name:"Moto E2 4g",brandName:"Motorola",price:"6999"},
    {srno:"P5",modelId:"5",name:"Nexus 5x",brandName:"LG",price:"24000"},
    {srno:"P6",modelId:"6",name:"Apple iPhone 5s",brandName:"Apple",price:"56000"},
];
var gridOptions={
    title:"Demo Grid",
    columnDefs:columnDefs,
    rowData:rowData
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    debugger;
    createDataGrid('#myGrid', gridOptions);
});



//library
function createDataGrid(div,gridDef){
    var gridTitle=gridDef.title
    var titleDiv='<div>'+gridTitle+'</div>';
    $(div).append(titleDiv);
    var table="<table id='tab1' border='1'></table>";
    $(div).append(table);
    $("#tab1").append("<tr id='tbheadres'></tr>");
    //render column headers
    $.each(gridDef.columnDefs,function(index,value){
        var columnName = gridDef.columnDefs[index].title;
        var columnHeader="<th>"+columnName+"</th>"
        $("#tbheadres").append(columnHeader);
    });

    $.each(gridDef.rowData,function(i1,val1){
        var rowId="row_"+i1;
        $("#tab1").append("<tr id="+rowId+"></tr>");
        $.each(gridDef.columnDefs,function(index,value){
            var field=gridDef.columnDefs[index].fieldName;
            var c1=gridDef.rowData[i1].field;
            var col="<td>"+c1+"</td>";
            $("#"+rowId).append(col);
        });
    });

}
```

After processing the nested $.each it give me nothing but "undefined" for every column in every row . I guess something is wrong at lines :

```
var field=gridDef.columnDefs[index].fieldName;
            var c1=gridDef.rowData[i1].field;
```

What i am doing wrong?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your JSON with JSONLint.com; I see at least you have extra commas in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line of code :

```
var c1=gridDef.rowData[i1].field;
```

to

```
var c1=gridDef.rowData[i1][field];
```